# PlayMorphia GeoSpatial Query

Tags: java, mongodb, geospatial, playframework-1.x, morphia

I'm using Play Framework v1.2.5 and the MongoDB Morphia module PlayMorphia v1.2.12 connecting to MongoDB v2.4.5.

I can't figure out how to do a geospatial query using Morphia.

For example, a basic query is fine:

```
//save a test address
new Address(47.5, -122.3, "123 South Main Street", "Seattle", "WA", "98109").save();

//now find it
List<Address> address = Address.q().filter("city", "Seattle").filter("street", "123 South Main Street").asList();
assertEquals(address.get(0).street,"123 South Main Street");
```

However, [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/modules/morphia-1.2.12/query) makes no mention about how to use MongoDB's $geoWithin $geoIntersects $near $nearSphere queries.

I tried using something like this, as hinted at in the documentation, but it didn't work.

```
List<Address> e = Address.q().filter("latlon near","[47.5, -122.3]").asList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish this, however, it's pretty ugly because the result needs to be casted.

```
List<Address> addresses = (List<Address>)(List<?>) Address.q().field("latlon").near(47.5, -122.3).asList();
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to cast to List<Address>.  Certainly that List<?> is unnecessary.  asList() already returns a List<T> so as long as your Query is properly typed, the return type should already be List<Address>

Answer (score 1):

I think the ultimate problem is that your parameter to filter is a String and not a double[].  Try something like:  Address.q().field("latlon").near(47.5, -122.3).  if you want $geoWithin specifially, you can use .field("latlon").within(Shape.center(new Point(47.5, -122.3), someRadius).  You'll need morphia 0.104 for that version of within().

Comment: Thanks.  Using Address.q().field("latlon").near(47.5, -122.3) did work - however, it's returning the super class (Model) which requires a bit of ugly casting.  Oh well, c'est la Java!

Comment: Must be a play-morphia thing.  Morphia proper should just be returning List<Address>.  I'm guessing that Address.q() isn't properly typed.